# Getting Chrome to open an `.html` file in a new window

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, html

Every time I double-click an `.html` file on my computer, Chrome opens it in a new tab in the most-recently-used window. I don't like that. I want it to open a new window.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control Panel -> Folder Options -> File Types -> HTML -> Advanced -> open -> Edit -> Replace `--` with `--new-window` -> Ok all the way back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use javascript to open the page in new window on load of the page. 
http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html

Answer (score 0):

My only thought would be to create a program to pass to google chrome with the --new-window argument, and have that program's icon set as chrome?

Answer (score 0):

See [Force Chrome to open new pages in new window, not tab? (when opened from a program)](https://superuser.com/questions/166479/force-chrome-to-open-new-pages-in-new-window-not-tab-when-opened-from-a-progr)

Answer (score 0):

The advanced GUI editor for file type associations has been removed from Windows Vista and Windows 7.  One needs to manually edit the registry or use 3rd party tools for such editing.

[How do I set advanced file associations in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7)

For manual registry settings, go to key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` and set the `(Default)` value to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "%1"`.  You may need to refresh Windows Explorer (log-out and log-in or restart the computer).

[Force Chrome to open new pages in new window, not tab? (when opened from a program)](https://superuser.com/questions/166479/force-chrome-to-open-new-pages-in-new-window-not-tab-when-opened-from-a-progr)