# Can I make Chrome always open links from other programs in a new window?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

It seems Chrome opens links from other programs into a tab of the most recently selected window -- even if, in OS X, this window is in a different fullscreen desktop. Very annoying.

Ideally I would have links from other programs always open into a new window.

Comment: has duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/166479/179299

Comment: The linked-to question does not provide a solution for os x and doesn't not ask about os x

Comment: The linked-to question asks a generic question, and there are answers for OS X and more. http://superuser.com/a/636064/4518

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the short answer, but it really is simple: press <kbd>shift</kbd> when clicking links.

edit:
from comments, it seems indeed i misread the question. can you please check if this applies? it is meant for IE, but who knows. IE and Chrome share some of their configs.

```
a.  Close Internet Explorer.
b. Click start->control Panel->Internet Options.
c. Click on the settings button under the section “Tab”.
d. Under “Open links from other programs in” select any one mentioned below to open other programs in new window.
• A new window - Opens links in new Internet Explorer windows.
• A new tab in the current window - Creates a new tab if an Internet Explorer window is opened; otherwise, opens a new Internet Explorer window
e.  Click Ok twice.
f. Then check if the issue is resolved.
```

source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/link-open-new-window-instead-of-tab-how-can-i-set/3dc36402-e71d-4bb2-970b-bc58b00fa029

Comment: "from other programs" - however, I would assume that this means the OP is referring to (what look like) hyperlinks outside of the browser? Shift+click is an in-browser feature.

Answer (score -2):

Please use the "[New Tab, New Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-new-window/dndlcbaomdoggooaficldplkcmkfpgff)" extension.
It will **always** open a new window...for everything.

Comment: this extension is not good... it always opens a new window, even when command-clicking from chrome iteself