# How can I make xfce open links in a new browser window on the current desktop, even if there is a browser open on another desktop?

Tags: browser, xfce

Normally, when an xfce app e.g. Thunar opens a file in an external program, it opens a new window on the current workspace to view that file. This is how I always want to open files and urls.

However, when I open a url in the terminal ("Open Link" in right click menu), it brings the browser window from another workspace to the current one and opens the url in a new tab. I tried to prevent this by setting "When a new window raises itself" to "Do nothing" in the Window Manager Tweaks, but now the url just opens in a new tab in an already open browser window without bringing it to the current desktop.

How can I get xfce to stop treating urls as a special case and just open them like a file path, in it's own window?

Comment: What browser are you using? and in what OS? ... well os does not really matter xfce is all that same.

Comment: Chromium, but the same thing happens when I change my default browser to Firefox in the Preferred Applications.

Comment: In Mozilla. go to edit - preferences - tabs  and un-check "Open new windows in a tab instead".  Does this solve your problem?

Comment: That works! If you put that as an answer, I will accept it. I thought it was xfce that was telling the browser to reuse windows.

Comment: For Chromium, see this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/166479/force-chrome-to-open-new-pages-in-new-window-not-tab-when-opened-from-a-progr#answer-465275).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, go to <kbd>Edit → Preferences → Tabs</kbd> and un-check "Open new windows in a tab instead".