# Problems with Chrome desktop shortcuts on WIN 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, shortcuts

I have several shortcuts to various websites on my desktop on Windows 10, and they open in Chrome, which is my default browser. However, whenever I use one, it always opens in a new window, even if I already have Chrome open. Also, this new window not only contains the link I clicked on, but it also opens a new tab in front of it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[Force Chrome to open new pages in new window, not tab? (when opened from a program)](https://superuser.com/q/166479) in that question he want chrome to open a new window instead of tab. Do the reverse should fix your problem maybe.-.

Comment: I didn't find anything helpful in there.