# How to make one particular bookmark always open in a new window

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I see many links like this, setting a global behavior that Chrome will open bookmarks in a new window. For example: [Force Chrome to open new pages in new window, not tab? (when opened from a program)](https://superuser.com/questions/166479/force-chrome-to-open-new-pages-in-new-window-not-tab-when-opened-from-a-progr)

But this is not what I want and I see no information on it. I am quite happy with Chrome's default of opening pages in a new tab. But I have one bookmark in particular that I want opened in a new window. I am well aware that I could right click the bookmark and specify "open in a new window", but I would like to specify this in the bookmark itself so that a simple click on it would achieve what I want. For an added bonus, I would also like it to open in "full screen" mode. Can such behaviors be specified in the bookmark itself?

Note: there are many links describing how web developers may achieve this, with philosophical arguments over whether a web designer should leave this up to the user or not. My ask here, though, is that of a user. I simply want one specific bookmark to always open in a new window, and preferably in full screen mode, without extra actions other than a click.

Is there a way to do these things?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a JavaScript Bookmarklet. I used [Bookmarklet Maker](https://caiorss.github.io/bookmarklet-maker/) to create the bookmarklet below.

Simply assign the bookmarklet maker code to the URL section of your bookmark.

The only thing you'll have to change is `www.google.com` to the URL that you want it to be.

For the sake of your convenience and willingness to make it how you want, here is the code I put into the bookmarklet maker. It could probably be done better but it was a quick implementation that works.

### Bookmarklet Maker Code

```
var popup = window.open("https://www.google.com", "popup", "fullscreen");
if (popup.outerWidth < screen.availWidth || popup.outerHeight < screen.availHeight)
{
   popup.moveTo(0,0);
   popup.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
}
```

### Bookmarklet Maker Output

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar popup %3D 
window.open("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com"%2C "popup"%2C 
"fullscreen")%3B%0A  if (popup.outerWidth < screen.availWidth %7C%7C 
popup.outerHeight < screen.availHeight)%0A  %7B%0A     
popup.moveTo(0%2C0)%3B%0A     popup.resizeTo(screen.availWidth%2C 
screen.availHeight)%3B%0A  %7D%7D)()%3B
```

### Want the correct favicon for the bookmarklet?

*I anticipated this being a question so I found a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/vinicius-stutz/29f759031b7e5a444733) explaining how to do it. I just copied the content to here in case it ever gets removed.*

1. Open the Bookmark Manager and export your bookmarks.
2. Open the exported html file in your favorite editor and look for the bookmarklet you want a favicon applied to.
3. Convert the 16x16 px (or greater) favicon you want to use into the BASE64 format (I used [Base64 Image Encoder](https://www.base64-image.de/)).
4. Now you can add the favicon via adding the `ICON="data:image/insert-your-base64-image-code-here"` attribute in the link.
5. Save the file and import it in the bookmark manager.

Done! If the favicon doesn’t show up, try clicking on the bookmarklet. Afterwards the changes should stick and you can delete the imported bookmarks folder. If you have sync activated the favicons on your bookmarklets will also show up on your other PC, Mac, smartphone etc.